# How is created_at calculated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, utc

When I create a new ActiveRecord instance, the `created_at` timestamp is saved into the database.

- How is this timestamp calculated?
- Is the time based on the server time?
- Is the time always in UTC timezone?
- Is there a documentation somewhere about this?

Comment: `created_at` is saved based on server's timezone. However, you can change the timezone though. Yes, by default it is in UTC.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna Thanks for the quick reply, Is there documentation about this somewhere? How did people gain this knowledge?

Comment: I don't think everything is in one place, about what is the default timezone and how to change, you can look [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the implementation of the `_create_record` method from ActiveRecord:

```
def _create_record
  if record_timestamps
    current_time = current_time_from_proper_timezone

    all_timestamp_attributes_in_model.each do |column|
      if !attribute_present?(column)
        _write_attribute(column, current_time)
      end
    end
  end

  super
end
```

And here is the implementation of the `current_time_from_proper_timezone` method:

```
def current_time_from_proper_timezone
      default_timezone == :utc ? Time.now.utc : Time.now
end
```

- The timestamp is UTC by default (calculated using `Time.now.utc`), however this can be changed in your configuration `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local` (In this case it will be calculated using `Time.now`)
- The time is based on your server
- It is UTC by default however you can change it by setting `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local`

If you would like to have a look at the code, here is the link: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb